# Background picture in pyqt4 qlabel

Tags: python, css, pyqt4

I modified this simple countdown timer form here: https://github.com/lunaryorn/snippets/blob/master/qt4/countdown.py as follows. Now I want to have a background image behind the countdown timer. Any ideas how to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QTime, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel, QPixmap



class CountdownWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, countdown, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.countdown = countdown
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter);
        #self.setPixmap(QPixmap('/tmp/test.png'));
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size : 400px; color : blue; }");
        self.setText(str(self.countdown))
        # setup the countdown timer
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._update_time)

    def start(self):
        # update the display every second
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def _update_time(self):
        # this gets called every seconds
        # adjust the remaining time
        #self.countdown = self.countdown.addSecs(-1)
        self.countdown = self.countdown -1
        # if the remaining time reached zero, stop the timer
        if self.countdown <= 0:
            self.timer.stop()
        # update the display
        self.setText(str(self.countdown))
        #self.setPixmap(QPixmap('/tmp/test.png')); #<--- doesn't work


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = CountdownWidget(30)
    widget.start()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the image as a CSS background:

```
self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font-size : 400px; color : blue; background-image: url('tmp/test.jpg');}");
```

Comment: @EMS: How would that work? The only alternative I can see is a custom `paintEvent`.

Comment: QLabel's setPixmap() should automatically cause that to happen. You might have to override paintEvent() though to ensure the timer thing appears the same way... I felt this should just be mentioned in passing because it's a common way for painting images in PyQT and a useful approach to consider. Other approaches might be more suited this specific task though.

Comment: @EMS: Ah, you are saying: Put the text on `QPixmap` and then put that on `QLabel`. Got it. Yes, that would work also.

Comment: I tried the QPixmap thing as commented out in my code above. But it didn't work.

Comment: @student: The way you are doing won't work, because every time you call `setPixmap` or `setText`, `QLabel` removes everything that was there before. You can use what I gave in my answer. What EMS is suggesting is a little bit different than what you are doing. With that method you'll basically construct a new `QPixmap` with your background, then paint your text on `QPixmap` and then set that `QPixmap` to `QLabel`.